# Vertex normal direction

Tags: mesh, normals

i want to change the direction of vertex normals of my planes inside the sphere, so they should be directed outside to sphere. As far i understood i may use data transfer modifier of edit normals modifier. But for some reasons it does't work,
could please someone help me?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Data transfer modifier creates *custom* normals.   Base vertex normals are preserved, even though the custom normals are used for rendering.  When you enable vertex normal display, it's showing you those base vertex normals, not custom split normals.  To see custom normals, you need to both enable the display of split normals in your overlays, and set the data transfer to cage display.

Comment: omg, i am dumb
Thank you!